# How to achieve X-axis scaling based on the x-ticks in pgfplots (i.e. the distance between the specified x-ticks is constant)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code for my pgfplot, however I would like to achieve custom x axis scaling just like the image attached below. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Accuracy vs Sparsity]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y err
50  92.67   0.125957348
60  92.7    0.020626807
70  92.49   0.003094064
80  92.04   0.005627052
90  91.61   0.005936952
95  90.2    0.032337642
96  90.45   0.111504465
97  89.83   0.006648374
98  90.04   0.062403899
99  89  0.01228753
99.3    88.35   0.026578355
99.5    87.67   0.007559671
99.7    86.73   0.006666544
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Network sparsity},
        ylabel={Test accuracy},
        ymin=80, ymax=95,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        xtick={50,70,90,95,98,99.7},
]
\addplot [color=blue,mark=x] table[x=x,y=y] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x coord trafo` and the inverse `x coord inv trafo` to make a custom x scale. You do not write *what* custom scale you want, so this is just a guess

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{100-ln(100-#1)}},
x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{100-exp(100-#1)}},
xlabel={Network sparsity},
ylabel={Test accuracy},
xmin=0, xmax=98.5,
ymin=90, ymax=94.5,
xmajorgrids=true, ymajorgrids=true,
xtick={20.0, 48.8, 67.2, 79.0, 86.6, 91.4, 94.5, 96.5, 97.7},
x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=45, /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1},
]
\addplot[red, mark=x, domain=20:98] {94-6/(100-x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with custom spacing of x values]